# Comparing multiple columns for a single row

Tags: python, dataframe, string-comparison

I am grouping columns and identifying rows that have different values for each group. For example: I can group columns A,B,C,D and delete column A because it is different (Row 2 is 2.1). Also, I can group columns E,F,G,H and delete column G because Row 1 (Row 0 is Blue).

```
      A |  B |  C   |   D    |   E   |   F   |   G  |   H
  | ---------------------------------------------------------|
0 | 1.0 |  1 | 1 in | 1 inch | Red   |  Red  | Blue |  Red
  | ---------------------------------------------------------|
1 | 2.0 |  2 | 2 in | 2 inch | Green | Green | Green| Green
  | ---------------------------------------------------------|
2 | 2.1 |  2 | 2 in | 2 inch | Blue  |  Blue | Blue |  Blue
```

What I have tried so far to compare values:

```
import difflib
text1 = '1.0'
text2 = '1 in'
text3 = '1 inch'
output = str(int(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, text1, text2, text3).ratio()*100))

output: '28'
```

This does not work well to compare numbers followed by a measurement like inches or mm. I then tried spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') and that works better but its still not there yet. Are there any ways to compare a group of values that are similar to 1.0, 1, 1 in, 1 inch?

Comment: You can use <df.E.equals(df.F)> for comparison and it will bring you a boolean as return.

Comment: Maybe you can try [fuzzy match](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzy-match/)

Comment: But for the columns like C and D, where you have strings, but you actually want to compare the numbers, I would create new columns with the extract of the numbers e.g. < df['c_num'] = df.C.apply( lambda x: int(re.search('[0-9]*', x).group() ) ) > and then compare those against each other, probably create a function for that.

Comment: gurezende Thanks for your comments! I think df.E.equals(df.F) works and I will work with it some more. Crystal Ill try fuzzy match as well. That looks like an interesting way to approach this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For columns with only strings, you can use pandas `df.equals()` that compares two dataframes or series (cols)

```
#Example    
df.E.equals(df.F)
```

You can use this function to compare many columns to a single one I called main or template, which should be the column where you have the "correct" values.

```
def col_compare(main_col, *to_compare):
  '''Compares each column from a list to another column
  Inputs: 
  * main_col: enter the column name (e.g. 'A')
  * to_compare: enter as many column names as you want (e.g. 'B', 'C') '''
  # Columns to compare to list
  to_compare = list(to_compare)
  # List to store results
  results = []

  # Compare columns from the list with the template column
  for col in to_compare:
    if not df[main_col].equals(df[col]):
      results.append(col)
  
  print(f'Main Column: {main_col}')
  print(f'Compared to: {to_compare}')
  return f"The columns that have different values from {main_col} are {results}"
```

e.g

```
`col_compare('E', 'F', 'G', 'H')`

output:
Main Column: E
Compared to: ['F', 'G', 'H']
The columns that have different values from E are ['G']
```

For the columns A, B, C and D, where you have numbers you want to compare, but pieces of strings after that, one option is to extract the numbers into new columns just for comparison and you can drop them later.
You can create new columns with the code below for each column with numbers and strings:

```
df['C_num'] = df.C.apply( lambda x: int(re.search('[0-9]*', x).group() ) )
```

and then use the function col_compare above to run the comparison between the numeric columns.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question. Crystal L recommended that I use FuzzyMatch and I found it to be useful. Here is the documentation:  https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python   Here are a couple of things I tried:

```
# Fucntion to compare length and similar characters
def levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(s, t, ratio_calc = False):
    """ levenshtein_ratio_and_distance:
        Calculates levenshtein distance between two strings.
        If ratio_calc = True, the function computes the
        levenshtein distance ratio of similarity between two strings
        For all i and j, distance[i,j] will contain the Levenshtein
        distance between the first i characters of s and the
        first j characters of t
    """
    # Initialize matrix of zeros
    rows = len(s)+1
    cols = len(t)+1
    distance = np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype = int)

    # Populate matrix of zeros with the indeces of each character of both strings
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1,cols):
            distance[i][0] = i
            distance[0][k] = k

    # Iterate over the matrix to compute the cost of deletions,insertions and/or substitutions    
    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if s[row-1] == t[col-1]:
                cost = 0 # If the characters are the same in the two strings in a given position [i,j] then the cost is 0
            else:
                # In order to align the results with those of the Python Levenshtein package, if we choose to calculate the ratio
                # the cost of a substitution is 2. If we calculate just distance, then the cost of a substitution is 1.
                if ratio_calc == True:
                    cost = 2
                else:
                    cost = 1
            distance[row][col] = min(distance[row-1][col] + 1,      # Cost of deletions
                                 distance[row][col-1] + 1,          # Cost of insertions
                                 distance[row-1][col-1] + cost)     # Cost of substitutions
    if ratio_calc == True:
        # Computation of the Levenshtein Distance Ratio
        Ratio = ((len(s)+len(t)) - distance[row][col]) / (len(s)+len(t))
        return Ratio
    else:
        # print(distance) # Uncomment if you want to see the matrix showing how the algorithm computes the cost of deletions,
        # insertions and/or substitutions
        # This is the minimum number of edits needed to convert string a to string b
        return "The strings are {} edits away".format(distance[row][col])
```

```
Str1= '1 mm'
Str2= '1 in'
Distance = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
print(Distance)
Ratio = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower(),ratio_calc = True)
print(Ratio)
```

```
import Levenshtein as lev
Str1= '1 mm'
Str2= '1 in'
Distance = lev.distance(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower()),
print(Distance)
Ratio = lev.ratio(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
print(Ratio)
```

```
# pip install fuzzywuzzy 
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
Str1= '2 inches'
Str2= '1 mm'

Ratio = fuzz.ratio(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
Partial_Ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
Token_Sort_Ratio = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Str1,Str2)
Token_Set_Ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(Str1,Str2)
print(Ratio)
print(Partial_Ratio)
print(Token_Sort_Ratio)
print(Token_Set_Ratio)
```